# Toggle Button Group in React

Tags: reactjs, dom

New to react and trying to use in a new electron learning project I have. I'm trying to build a really basic drawing app.

I created a ToolbarButton class. That would represent each button and a Toolbar that would manage the button group. Example If you pick a 'primary' tool then it should turn off all other primary tools and leave only your current selection.

In jQuery I'd just do something like

```
   let button = $(this);
   let toolbar = $(this).parent();
   toolbar.find('button.toolbar-button').removeClass('active');
   button.addClass('active');
```

How would I do the same in react? I can toggle what I want to with setState from within the ToggleButton but separating it out into a prop seems to be an answer, but then I need to have the Toolbar manage the button 'active' states and I'm not sure how to do that. Think the answer is in ReactDOM, super newbie to react so apologize if the answer is overly obvious.

```
import React from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import { ButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ChromePicker} from 'react-color';

class ToolbarButton extends React.Component
{
    state = 
    {
        active: false
    }

    handleClick = ()=> {

        if(this.props.onClick)
        {
            this.props.onClick();
        }         

        this.setState({ active: !this.state.active});
    }

    render(){
        return <div className={`btn btn-primary${this.state.active ? ' active' : ''}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</div>
    }
}

class ColorPickerButton extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            displayColorPicker: false,
            color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a:1 } 
        }
    }

    state = {
        flyout: 'bottom',
        displayColorPicker: false,
        color: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a:1 } 
    }

    /* This button should have an option to display how the colorpicker flys out */
    static flyoutStyles =
    {
        normal: { },
        top: {top: '0px' },
        bottom: { top: '100%' },
        left: { right: '100%' },
        right: { left: '100%' }
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({ displayColorPicker: !this.state.displayColorPicker});
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ displayColorPicker: false });
    }

    handleChange = (color) => {
        this.setState({ color: color.rgb });
    }

    stopPropagation = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    render()
    {
        const swatchStyle = {
            backgroundColor: `rgba(${this.state.color.r},
                ${this.state.color.g},
                ${this.state.color.b},
                ${this.state.color.a})`,
            height: '16px',
            width: '16px',
            border: '1px solid white'
        };

        const popup = {
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 2,
            top: 'calc(100% + 2px)'
        };

        const cover = {
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px',
            right: '0px',
            left: '0px',
            bottom: '0px',
        };

        return (
            <ToolbarButton onClick={this.handleClick} active={this.state.displayColorPicker}>
                <div style={swatchStyle} />
                {
                    this.state.displayColorPicker ?
                        <div style={popup} onClick={this.stopPropagation}>
                             <div style={ cover } onClick={ this.handleClose }/>
                             <ChromePicker color={this.state.color} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    : null
                }
            </ToolbarButton>
        );
    }
}

export class CanvasToolbar extends React.Component
{
    handleClick = (e) => {

    }

    render(){
        return (<div className="CanvasToolbar">
            <ButtonGroup vertical>
                <ToolbarButton>
                    <FontAwesome name='paint-brush' />
                </ToolbarButton>
                <ToolbarButton>
                <FontAwesome name='eraser' />
                </ToolbarButton>
                <ToolbarButton>
                    <FontAwesome name='magic' />
                </ToolbarButton>
                <ColorPickerButton />
            </ButtonGroup>
        </div>);
    }
}
```